# Retrieve SelectedItems from a RadGrid

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I have a RadGrid from Telerik with a GridClientSelectColumn column. When the user checks records and clicks the action button the SelectedItems is empty.

Is there any way to retrieve SelectedItems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The selected items should be there unless you call Rebind() for the grid explicitly from outer control. Tested on modified version of [this sample](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/client/selecting/defaultcs.aspx), worked with no issues.

Comment: Bingo! I was using Rebind() so I had SelectedItems empty.